# Can you somehow overload the query in a method?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core-mvc, dto

So there's a `Customer` and a `Seller` and they're both `User`. The only difference between them is that seller has a `NameOfBusiness` and customer does not.

In the DAL I have this code:

```
 public void CreateCustomer(UserDTO u)
 {
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
         string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[User](FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password, HouseNumber, Adress, Zip) " +
             "VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @UserName, @Password, @HouseNumber, @Adress, @Zip)";
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.FirstName;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.LastName;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.UserName;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.Password;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@HouseNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = u.Housenumber;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@Adress", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.Adress;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@Zip", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.Zip;

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
 }


public void CreateSeller(UserDTO u)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[User](FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password, HouseNumber, Adress, Zip, NameOfBusiness) " +
            "VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @UserName, @Password, @HouseNumber, @Adress, @Zip, @NameOfBusiness)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.FirstName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.LastName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.UserName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.Password;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@HouseNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = u.Housenumber;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Adress", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.Adress;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Zip", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.Zip;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NameOfBusiness", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.NameOfBusiness;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to overload the query OR change the query so that you can fill in a *NULL* for `NameOfBusiness`?

Comment: Always use `CreateSeller` method and set `UserDTO.NameOfBusiness = null` for the passed parameter if it is a customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option A Do almost nothing

Rename `CreateSeller` to `Create` and use it as it is. Name of business is likely empty for customers already.

## Option B Do just a little bit

`Create` could take in a `bool` parameter and clear name of business.

```
public void Create(UserDTO u, bool isSeller )
{
...
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NameOfBusiness", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 
                   isSeller ? u.NameOfBusiness : null;
```

## Option C. Craft

`Create` could take in a `bool` parameter and modify the query and the `Parameters` accordingly. Something like the following.

```
public void Create(UserDTO u, bool isSeller)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[User](FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password, HouseNumber, Adress, Zip" +
            (isSeller ? "NameOfBusiness" : "") +
            ") VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @UserName, @Password, @HouseNumber, @Adress, @Zip" +
            (isSeller ? "@NameOfBusiness" : "") +
            ")";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            // (...)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Zip", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.Zip;
            if(isSeller) {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@NameOfBusiness", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u.NameOfBusiness;
            }
```